# multi thread python psycopg2

Tags: python, multithreading, postgresql, psycopg2

I'm using multi thread inside my program in python. I've got 3 queues. In one of them I'm inserting data to postgres database. But before, I need to check if in the database already exists row with specific domain name. So I've got:

```
class AnotherThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, another_queue):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.another_queue = another_queue


    def run(self):
        while True:
            chunk = self.another_queue.get()
            if chunk is not '':
                dane = chunk[0].split(',',2)

                cur.execute("SELECT exists(SELECT 1 FROM global where domain = %s ) ", (domena,))
                jest = cur.fetchone()
                print(jest)
```

It's a part of code my third queue. I'm connecting to database here (in main() function):

```
queue = Queue.Queue()
out_queue = Queue.Queue()
another_queue = Queue.Queue()

for i in range(50):
    t = ThreadUrl(queue, out_queue)
    t.setDaemon(True)
    t.start()

for host in hosts:
    queue.put(host)

for i in range(50):
    dt = DatamineThread(out_queue,another_queue)
    dt.setDaemon(True)
    dt.start()

conn_str = "dbname='{db}' user='user' host='localhost' password='pass'"
conn = psycopg2.connect(conn_str.format(db='test'))
conn.autocommit = True
cur = conn.cursor()

for i in range(50):
    dt = AnotherThread(another_queue)
    dt.setDaemon(True)
    dt.start()



queue.join()
out_queue.join()
another_queue.join()

cur.close()
conn.close()
```

When I run my script I've got:

```
(False,)
(False,)
(False,)
(False,)
(False,)
(False,)
(False,)
(False,)
(False,)
Exception in thread Thread-128:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "domains.py", line 242, in run
    jest = cur.fetchone()
ProgrammingError: no results to fetch

Exception in thread Thread-127:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "domains.py", line 242, in run
    jest = cur.fetchone()
ProgrammingError: no results to fetch

(False,)
(False,)
(False,)
```

Why for some of them I'm getting an error?

Answer (score 2):

This may have to do with the fact that all threads share the same connection and cursor. I could imagine a case where `cur.execute()` is run, then `cur.fetchone()` by another thread, then `cur.fetchone()` again by (yet another or the same or the previous) thread, with no `cur.execute` in between. The Python GIL would switch between threads per line (statement). Thus, that second time `fetchone()` is run, there are no results anymore: there's only one row to fetch initially, and that's now been exhausted.
You probably want to isolate each cursor, or somehow make the `cur.execute(...); cur.fetchone()` commands atomic.

---

The answer to the question [are transactions in postgresql via psycopg2 per cursor or per connection](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/75395/are-transactions-in-postgresql-via-psycopg2-per-cursor-or-per-connection) (DBA StackExchange link) mentions transactions are per connection, so isolating cursors probably won't help you.