# What is correct way to use psycopg2 cursors in threads?

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, psycopg2, psql

I feel the answer to my question is in these two SO questions, but I find the answers very poorly worded (or above my pay grade)

1. [multi thread python psycopg2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48630476/multi-thread-python-psycopg2)
2. [Are transactions in PostgreSQL via `psycopg2` per-cursor or per-connection?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/75395/are-transactions-in-postgresql-via-psycopg2-per-cursor-or-per-connection)

**Question:** What is the correct way to use psycopg2 to ensure it is thread safe

**Option 1: Each thread has its own cursor**

```
import threading
import psycopg2

conn = psycopg2.connect (
    host=127.0.0.1,
    user='john',
    password='1234',
    dbname='foo',
    port=1234)

class Foo (threading.Thread):
    def __init__ (self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)

    def run (self):
        global conn

        cur = conn.cursor()
        sql_query="SELECT * from foo;"
        print(cur.execute (sql_query))
        conn.commit()

num_threads = 100
threads = []

for i in seq (num_threads):
    threads.append (Foo())

for i in seq (num_threads):
    threads[i].start()

for i in seq (num_threads):
    threads[i].join()
```

**Option 2: Each thread has it's own connection**

```
import threading
import psycopg2

db_conn = psycopg2.connect (
    host=127.0.0.1,
    user='john',
    password='1234',
    dbname='foo',
    port=1234)

class Foo (threading.Thread):
    def __init__ (self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.conn = psycopg2.connect (
            host=127.0.0.1,
            user='john',
            password='1234',
            dbname='foo',
            port=1234)

    def run (self):
        cur = self.conn.cursor()
        sql_query="SELECT * from foo;"
        print(cur.execute (sql_query))
        conn.commit()

num_threads = 100
threads = []

for i in seq (num_threads):
    threads.append (Foo())

for i in seq (num_threads):
    threads[i].start()

for i in seq (num_threads):
    threads[i].join()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Each thread should have its own database connection.

A PostgreSQL connection can handle only one statement at a given time (unless you are using a [server side cursor](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-declare.html), but even then the connection can handle only one `FETCH` at the same time).

So if several threads were to share a database connection, they'd have to coordinate carefully to make sure that only one thread uses the connection at the same time. For example, you cannot send a new query while another thread is still waiting for a query result.

Comment: Thanks. If I may be greedy, could you quickly comment on whether there is a performance/bottleneck issues with too many DB connections?

Comment: It is definitely a bad idea to have too many database connections. That's why you are using a *connection pool* that contains a limited number of persistent database connections. For every transaction a thread wants to perform, you grab one of the pooled connections and return it when you are done. I am sure there is built-in connection pooling in  psycopg2.

Answer (score 2):

Seams connections can be shared, fom the Psycopg 2.9.3 documentation: https://www.psycopg.org/docs/connection.html

Connections are thread safe and can be shared among many threads. See Thread and process safety for details.

Comment: This worked for me. I was using Process, which failed on newer Linux computers, but threading.Thread did the trick.

Comment: You need to be very careful when sharing a connection across threads because commits and rollbacks are performed for the entire connection. If you have a multistep transaction and another thread performs a commit in the middle, you may not like the result.